# How do I get my for loop to go to the next character?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, dereference

I'm creating a code that will output a number based on the input letter. My code is stuck was stuck on a loop of doing character 0 repeatedly. Friend said that char Check = userInput.charAt(numTelephone); would fix it. When I placed that into my code I recieved the error: error: char cannot be dereferenced   `char Check = userInput.charAt(numTelephone);`

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class PhoneWords {

     public static void main(String []args){
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        int numTelephone;
       
        char userInput;
        userInput = scnr.next().charAt(0);
         
        System.out.println("Enter a telephone number using letters (EXIT to quit): ");
        System.out.println("The corresponding telephone number is: ");
        
        if ((userInput >= 'A') || (userInput <= 'Z') || (userInput >= 'a') || (userInput <= 'z')){
            
            for (numTelephone = 0; numTelephone < 7; numTelephone++){
            char Check = userInput.charAt(numTelephone);
                     if (numTelephone == 3){
                        System.out.print("-");
                     }
               switch (userInput) {
                   case 'A':
                   case 'a':
                   case 'B':
                   case 'b':
                   case 'C':
                   case 'c':
                       System.out.print("2");
                       break;
                   case 'D':
                   case 'd':
                   case 'E':
                   case 'e':
                   case 'F':
                   case 'f':
                       System.out.print("3");
                       break;
                   case 'G':
                   case 'g':
                   case 'H':
                   case 'h':
                   case 'I':
                   case 'i':
                       System.out.print("4");
                       break;
                   case 'J':
                   case 'j':
                   case 'K':
                   case 'k':
                   case 'L':
                   case 'l':
                       System.out.print("5");
                       break;
                   case 'M':
                   case 'm':
                   case 'N':
                   case 'n':
                   case 'O':
                   case 'o':
                       System.out.print("6");
                       break;
                   case 'P':
                   case 'p':
                   case 'Q':
                   case 'q':
                   case 'R':
                   case 'r':
                   case 'S':
                   case 's':
                       System.out.print("7");
                       break;
                   case 'T':
                   case 't':
                   case 'U':
                   case 'u':
                   case 'V':
                   case 'v':
                       System.out.print("8");
                       break; 
                   case 'W':
                   case 'w':
                   case 'X':
                   case 'x':
                   case 'Y':
                   case 'y':
                   case 'Z':
                   case 'z':
                       System.out.print("9");
                       break;
                    default:
                        break;
               }
            }
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: `userInput` is already a `char` - maybe you want to accept a String using `nextLine` ?

Answer (score -1):

The type char is primitive -- not an object -- so it cannot be dereferenced

Dereferencing is the process of accessing the value referred to by a reference. Since a char is already a value (not a reference), it can not be dereferenced.

so get the char from the given input like:

```
char userInput = scnr.nextLine().charAt(0);
```

And comment this line which is suggested by your friend which is not used any where:

```
//char Check = userInput.charAt(numTelephone);
```

Comment: Now the error is:       PhoneWords.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
                char Check = userInput.charAt(numTelephone);
                                      ^
  symbol:   method charAt(int)
  location: variable userInput of type Character
1 error

Comment: Updated my answer, please try this it should work now

Comment: Any chance to try the above solution? @Ian